# Importing flask.ext.wtf

Tags: python, flask, package, flask-wtforms, python-venv

I am using venv, and I develop using eclipse .
I want to add a contact page .

I did :

```
$ . bin/activate
$ pip install flask-wtf
```

And I import some modules in the forms.py :

I used this :

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
```

and then this :

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import TextField, BooleanField
```

No one of them worked because I had this error :

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf
```

Comment: Ive run the script exactly the virtual environment?

Comment: Did you [configure eclipse's pydev to use the python interpreter of the virtualenv](http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2010/04/pydev-and-virtualenv.html)?

Comment: Yes I think that the configuration is good, and I still have the problem .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by using `venv/bin/pip install flask-wtf` instead of `pip install flask-wtf` (even if I activated venv before the second command `. bin/activate` )

Answer (score 17):

What version of flask-wtf did you install? 
Since version 9 you do all of the field imports from WTForms not from Flask-WTF.

So your imports will be (note that according to [`docs`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) import statement was changed):

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField
```

Comment: When I activate `virtualenv` and type `pip show flask`, the version that it shows is : `Version: 0.10.1` . When I do the imports like you said : `ImportError: No module named flask_wtf`

Comment: ps: I installed flask_wtf using pip of my venv.

Comment: That is the version of Flask you have.  Check the version of Flask-WTF with pip show FLask-WTF or a pip freeze to see all the packages. It should say something like Flask-WTF==0.9.3 or whichever version you have. If its not there pip install Flask-WTF and your problem should be fixed! Be sure your editor is using your virtenv as well.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from eclipse who searches for those modules in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/` instead searching for it in my `venv` folder .

Answer (score 6):

I had to use

```
from flask_wtf import Form
```

instead of

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing different import styles and re-installing flask, flask-wtf, if it still does not works : then in the `config.py`( "`config.py` may be of different name eg app_config.py etc)

insert the line

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'venv/Lib/site-packages'))
```

set the lib path of your own app , in my case it was `"venv/Lib/site-packages"`